# CANoe multiple instances using win32com

Tags: python, com, canoe

I'm trying to create two CANoe instances using Python (win32com module).

I'm trying to create two objects and open the configurations, but it creates only one instance. How can I achieve creating two CANoe instances?

I disabled the option in the application which was to permit only one instance (I am able to open two CANoe instances manually).

```
application = win32com.client.DispatchEx("CANoe.Application")

application.Open(config)

application2 = win32com.client.DispatchEx("CANoe.Application")

application2.Open(config2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this but **not recommended**.

You can navigate to the CAN.ini file and change the following under `[System]` tag. (Default value is 0)

```
SingleCOMClient=1
```

A warning is mentioned just about this line. So, use this option with CAUTION!

Restart CANoe once to bring this change to effect.

The .ini file can be found in `C:\ProgramData\Vector\CANoe\<version>\CAN.ini`

**NOTE** : Using `DispatchEx` will create a new instance by default. 
 Using `Dispatch` will first check if any existing CANoe instance is available and attach to that instance. If no open instance, then it will create a new one.