# Is it possible to open new Canoe Config everytime using Dispatch COmmand in Python?

Tags: configuration, dispatch, capl, canoe

I am using the dispatch command to open Canoe application. But unfortunately I could see that the last saved Canoe config is opened whenever I run this command . But my probem statement is to open New Blank Canoe configuration everytime I run this command .Is it Possible?

Can we also describle the type of Canoe config (CANFD or 1 Ch CAN 500kbps or etc)using the same command?

Thanks in advance

The sample code is as below

import win32com.client
win32com.client.Dispatch('CANoe.Application')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CANoe multiple instances using win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692488/canoe-multiple-instances-using-win32com)

Comment: Thanks for the link .. but i am not looking for multiple Canoe instance rather I am interested to open blank configuration everytime i run the above code

Answer (score 0):

In CANoe, you must check the option in File > Options > General > Save/Open > "Always start with default Configuration". I am using CANoe 16 SP4.

Then you can use the Dispatch Command.

Answer (score -1):

you need to do following:

1. save blank template as .cfg 
   I dont sure if you could open directly the template, but this is kind of workaround that can solve your query.
   ex: you want 2 different config: Config1 CANFD1 1000kbps, Config2 CAN1 500kbps.
2. adapt command to load define configuration
   in CANoe Help also provide example of Command Line Parameters

   CANoe64.EXE /f "D:\CANSystemDemo\CANSystemDemo.CFG"

so if you want to open config for CAN1 500kbps, you have to send command:

```
CANoe64.EXE /f "C:\yourDirectory\Config2.CFG"
```